# How to decrypt the Obfuscated J2me file? (For reverse engineering)

Tags: mobile, jar, obfuscation, encryption

Im looking into decrypt the jar files. (Obfuscated j2me/jar file).

using decompier, im not able to get the exact files & folders, b'caz of obfuscation.

is thr any possibilities  to break the obfuscated jar file?

Please, im expecting your' valuable replies..

Advance Thanks to all.

By & bye from Munna

Answer (score 1):

No. The renaming of files (and variables, etc) during obfuscation is a one-way operation. There are tools that can assist you, but if you want them to have better names you'll have to figure them out yourself really.

Comment: Thanks ZoFrex, obfuscation don;t have an any single flaw? (atleast)

Comment: There are commercial Java decompilers that can take a byte-code stream and reconstruct a reasonable Java program out of it.  But that's as far as you're likely to go.